# Mudar banco de dados woocommerce wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados, wordpress, woocommerce

Fiz um sistema para o back-end de uma loja em wordpress que usa o plugin woocommerce.
O cliente solicitou que eu fizesse um sistema de login com registro personalizado, pois bem, eu fiz o sistema com bootstrap, php, jquery.

Vale lembrar que esse sistema tem uma tabela exclusiva dela com seus respectivos dados para autenticar o usuario.

Já integrei a maior parte no site dele e configurei as devidas regras de autenticidade e talz, porém surgiu a necessidade de fazer com que o woocommerce pegue os dados da minha tabela de registro para configurar o checkout.

não achei em lugar nenhuma alguma explicação de como pegar as informações de uma tabela que não seja a padrão do woocommerce.

```
meu sistema de login é por session.
```

pelo que vi no phpmyadmin existe duas tabelas: wp_836(woocommerce) e a minha "cadastro".

como fazer com que a tabela cadastro seja a principal tabela do plugin woocommerce? segue os dados:

> id, 
>   empresa,
>   email,
>   senha,
>   CNPJ,
>   endereco,
>   cep,
>   cidade,
>   estado,
>   telefone,
>   celular,
>   data,
>   token.

a loja já está toda montada e não quero ter que refazer tudo só pra mexer nisso.

pelo que estou vendo fiquei muito tempo fuçando os arquivos do plugin mas é muita gambiarra editar arquivo por arquivo, o ideal é se eu pudesse fazer alguma function no functions.php para setar isso, ou algo parecido.

Desde já agradeço quem puder me ajudar.

Outras alternativas são bem vindas.

Comment: Eu precisei fazer um sistema de login personalizado também no Wordpress, porém não criei tabela diferente apenas implementei os campos a mais na própria tabela de login do Wordpress

Comment: olá, obrigado pela resposta, pois é Larissa, porém eu nao entendi muito bem essa tabela do WP, e não sei onde ela armazena os dados de login, você sabe me explicar?